# Насколько грамотное решение задачки?

Tags: javascript

Данная задачка была на одном из собеседований в ай-ти компанию.
Свертка списка в диапазоны.
Дан список интов, повторяющихся элементов в списке нет.
Нужно преобразовать это множество в строку, сворачивая соседние по числовому ряду числа в диапазоны.
Примеры:

[1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 9, 8, 11, 0] => "0-5, 8-9, 11"

[1, 4, 3, 2] => "1-4"

[1, 4] => "1, 4"

Comment: Я бы отсортировал, потом от каждого элемента отнял его индекс в массиве и сгруппировал по полученным значениям.

Answer (score 3):

Про грамотность уже ответили в комментариях к решению (на будущее - пожалуйста, помещай код ***в вопрос***), добавлю только замечание по кодстайлу: отсутствие `;` и группировки объявлений, однозначно является минусом.
Из неоднозначного/субъективного: имхо, это спагетти-код... то есть, понимание логики всех ветвистых конкатенаций требует усилий (я не могу ткнуть пальцем в произвольное место твоего кода и сразу назвать состояние его выполнения в этой точке).

---

На собеседовании, я бы решил задачу "в лоб", через массивы - и ответил бы на обычные вопросы: о логике решения; его преимуществах (легкое изменение формата вывода); и недостатках (производительность).

Потому что работодателям обычно требуется не изящество решений, а скорость их разработки, и потенциальная способность их поддерживать/развивать.

```js
const lists = [
  [1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 9, 8, 11, 0], 
  [1, 4, 3, 2], 
  [1, 4]
]; 
console.log(lists.map(toRanges).join('\n')); 

function toRanges(list) {
  const last = list.length - 1; 
  if (!last) return String(list[0]); 
  const sorted = list.sort((a, b) => a - b), 
        ranges = []; 
  for (var r = [sorted[0]], i = 1; i <= last; ++i) {
    if (sorted[i] - sorted[i - 1] === 1) continue; 
    if (i !== 1) r.push(sorted[i - 1]); 
    ranges.push(r); 
    r = [sorted[i]]; 
  }
  if (r[0] !== sorted[last]) r.push(sorted[last]); 
  ranges.push(r);
  return ranges.map(r => r.join('-')).join(', '); 
}
```

Логика решения всего в три шага:

- Если элемент в списке один, то сразу возвращаем его как диапазон.
- Иначе, просто проходим по отсортированному списку со второго элемента, проверяя разность каждого числа с предыдущим.
  Когда разность >1 и текущий элемент не является первым проверяемым (чтобы первый одиночный диапазон не дублировался) - берем предыдущий элемент как конец диапазона, а текущий элемент делаем началом нового диапазона.
- После чего закрываем последним элементом списка последний диапазон (если тот не одиночный), добавляем в найденные диапазоны, и возвращаем их.

**Upd.**:

Добавив (из ответа) четвертый список, которого нет в задании, нашел баг в своем решении - при одиночном диапазоне в середине отсортированного списка, условие `if (i !== 1)` естественно не спасает.
Быстрофикс счетчиком промежуточных элементов диапазона:

```js
const lists = [
  [1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 9, 8, 11, 0], 
  [1, 4, 3, 2], 
  [1, 4], 
  [2, 5, 1, 3, 8, 9, 11, 0, 4, 12, 14, 16, 17, 28, 19]
]; 
console.log(lists.map(toRanges).join('\n')); 

function toRanges(list) {
  const last = list.length - 1; 
  if (!last) return String(list[0]); 
  const sorted = list.sort((a, b) => a - b), 
        ranges = []; 
  for (var r = [sorted[0]], cnt = 0, i = 1; i <= last; ++i) {
    if (sorted[i] - sorted[i - 1] === 1) {
      ++cnt; 
      continue; 
    }
    if (cnt > 0) r.push(sorted[i - 1]); 
    ranges.push(r); 
    r = [sorted[i]]; 
    cnt = 0; 
  }
  if (r[0] !== sorted[last]) r.push(sorted[last]); 
  ranges.push(r);
  return ranges.map(r => r.join('-')).join(', '); 
}
```

Исходный вариант оставляю как есть - иначе было бы неспортивно :)

---

До варианта предложенного **Akina** в комментарии к вопросу (группировка по разностям отсортированных значений и их индексов) - прямсразу, я бы точно не додумался... а может, и не додумался бы вовсе :)

Comment: ИМХО код ТС гораздо читабельнее вашего. В вашем без дебага не разобрался :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, Так под кодом же достаточно подробное объяснение (на русском)... А что именно в коде нечитаемо? Уточняю чтобы в будущем стараться писать понятнее.

Comment: Конечно, это вкусовщина, но например `var r = [sorted[0]]` в инициализации цикла - усложняет. От цикла ожидаешь, что он будет заниматься итерацией и ничего больше. Использование continue в цикле, не "говорящее" имя переменной `r`. Опять же, много мелких таких деталей усложняет читаемость кода. Ну и совсем личное-личное - условие if и блок кода в одну строку :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, спасибо! Все замечания (кроме `continue`) ясны.

Answer (score 2):

Исправил немного ваше решение.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 9, 8, 11, 0]
const arr2 = [1, 2,3,4]
const arr3 = [1, 4]
const arr4 = [2, 5, 1, 3, 8, 9, 11, 0, 4, 12, 14, 16, 17, 28, 19]

function range (arr) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)
  let str = arr[0]
  let iteration
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i-1] + 1 === arr[i]) {
      iteration = true
    } else {
      if (!iteration) {
        str += ',' + arr[i]
      } else {
        str += '-' + arr[i-1] + ',' + arr[i]
        iteration = false
      }
    }
  }
  if (iteration)
     str += '-' + arr[arr.length-1]    
  return str
}

console.log(range(arr1))
console.log(range(arr2))
console.log(range(arr3))
console.log(range(arr4))
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr1 = [1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 9, 8, 11, 0]
const arr2 = [1, 4, 3, 2]
const arr3 = [1, 4]
const arr4 = [2, 5, 1, 3, 8, 9, 11, 0, 4, 12, 14, 16, 17, 28, 19]

function range (arr) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)
  let str = arr[0]
  let iteration
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] + 1 === arr[i + 1]) {
      iteration = true
    } else {
      if (!iteration) {
        str += ',' + arr[i]
      } else {
        str += '-' + arr[i]
        if (arr[i + 1] + 1 === arr[i + 2]) {
          str += ',' + arr[i + 1]
        }
        iteration = false
      }
    }
  }
  return str
}

console.log(range(arr1))
console.log(range(arr2))
console.log(range(arr3))
console.log(range(arr4))
```

Comment: `if (arr[i + 1] + 1 === arr[i + 2])` странная проверка. даже очень странная.

Comment: `console.log(range(arr4))` даёт "0-5,8-9,11-12,14-17,19,28", хотя я 15 в массиве в упор не вижу.